# inotifywait not executing when files are created simultaneaously in watched folder

Tags: inotify

I am using inotifywait for executing automatically a script created with my web app in a given folder.

I have setup inotifywait to watch file creation events in a folder and i am looking for a way to automatically execute commands generated in the created files.

I have setup a sh file running as a service in which i have put the following code :

```
#!/bin/bash
inotifywait -q  --format '%f' -e create /Mainfolder/sub/sub-1/temp|
    while read FILENAME 
        do   
          
            cust=$(basename "$FILENAME")
        
            IFS='-' read -r -a array <<< "$cust"
        
            if  [ ${array[0]} = "doactions" ]  
        
                then 
                chown root:root /Mainfolder/sub/sub-1/temp/${cust}
                sed -i 's/\r$//' /Mainfolder/sub/sub-1/temp/${cust}
                chmod 755  /Mainfolder/sub/sub-1/temp/${cust}
                ./Mainfolder/sub/sub-1/temp/${cust}
            fi
        done
```

Everything runs smoothly when only a single file is created in the target folder but when several files are created at the same time nothing works.
The file generated by my web app is a txt file that contains several command lines.
I wonder if inotifywait is just not watching the target folder while the code of generated file is being executed...if so is there a way to solve such issue ?
Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't you be using the `-m` (monitor) option? Otherwise `inotifywait` will exit after the first event.

Comment: I have tried with it but no difference

Comment: Try testing it with something simpler than that overcomplicated bash code. Keep in mind that the `%f` format means the file name, not the full path.

Comment: Your inotifywait triggers when the files are *created*, but then your `sed -i` immediately tries to read and recreate them, even before they were written to and closed. That can only work by fluke.

Comment: Try with `-e close_write`. Example (untested): `d=/that/dir; inotifywait -qme close_write --format %f "$d" | while read -r f; do case $f in doactions-*) sed -i 's/\r$//' "$d/$f" && chmod 755 "$d/$f" && "$d/$f"; esac; done`